# jOOQ - DSL.dateAdd with Field<Timestamp>

Tags: java, sql, jooq

One of my generated Tables has a field called `start` which is of Type `Field<Timestamp>` (in the database the column is actualy a `datetime`). The same table also has a field `duration` which holds an `Int`.

I would like to add the `duration` to the `start`. I've found `DSL.dateAdd` but this requires a `Field<Date>`. How can i convert the `Timestamp` field to a `Date` field so that i can use it like in the following example?

```
DSL.dateAdd(MYTABLE.START, MYTABLE.DURATION, DatePart.MINUTE)
```

EDIT: 
Little bit more research on my part revealed that there is a `DSL.timestampAdd` function which solved my problem.

Comment: Did you know that you can also provide an answer to your own question and accept that? This will help future visitors see that this question already has a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the [Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.4.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#timestampAdd-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) there is also a method called `timestampAdd` which does exactly that.